# How to push view controller without controller

Tags: swift, uikit

I want to push view controller but i dont have navigation in my collectionViewController, i want to go to another controller

I use UIKIt + Swift 5

```swift
 override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


        navigationController?.pushViewController(InternalController(), animated: true)
    }
```

How i can make like that

Answer (score 0):

Just instantiate the new ViewController and present it:

```swift
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MyStoryboardName", bundle: nil)
let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "someViewController")
self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
if let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginView") as? LoginViewController {
    present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```